# Bad Font-Measuring Performance under Windows 8.1

Tags: wpf, performance, fonts

Why does the following little loop (in c#) perform so bad using current version of WPF (.NET 4.5.2) if i change the font-family from "Segoe UI" to "Arial" (or something else...tried "Times New Roman" and "Courier New" - Same problem)?

```
var tb = new TextBlock {Text = "Testtext", FontFamily = new FontFamily("Arial")};

for(int i = 0; i < 100000; i++)
{
    tb.InvalidateMeasure();
    tb.Measure(new Size(double.MaxValue, double.MaxValue));
}
```

With font-family set to Arial this block of code takes about 7.6s on my machine. Font-family set to "Segoe UI" takes about 1.9s. Why do other fonts than Segoe UI perform so bad during measurement? Is there any tweak around, that does avoid this enormous loss in performance?

Edit: As i found found out, "Tahoma", "Lucida Sans" and "Microsoft Sans Serif" are being measured really fast, also. Is this some "System-internal font"-thing?

Comment: Well, bad idea, you force WPF to recalculate the layout of that TextBlock.  The MSDN article is not silent about it either: "Frequent calls to InvalidateMeasure or in particular to UpdateLayout have significant performance consequences."  The snippet is too fake to guess what you are really trying to do.

Comment: Yes, i know, it's really constructed and broken down to a minimal reproducable example. The whole component is a custom datagrid with complex ui- and data-virtualization. If i set the font of my grid to, let's say "Arial", the scrolling-performance gets really bad. So i tracked the problem down to the measurement of my single grid-cells, which basically measure single textblocks. My problem is NOT, that the code above is slow. My problem IS, that changing the font impacts measurement in such an enormous amount...

Comment: Sorry i deleted my answer since it don't actually solve the issue, my aim was to show that disabling the Font Cache service won't help ...hope some body have a good explanation to that!

Comment: Np, Joseph! At least for me it was quite helpful, seeing other people experiencing the same problem :)

Comment: I've provided a fix and partially answered "why" in [my answer over here.][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25041233/why-does-the-tahoma-font-render-faster-than-arial-in-wpf/